# How to drop some specific colums (having a pattern) in a MultiIndex header?

Tags: pandas

In some code, I ended up with a multindex header with some intruder columns that I'm trying to get rid of. These columns have the pattern `'[A-Z]\d+'` and they can be located anywhere in the inner level .

My dataframe looks like this one :

```
import pandas as pd

section_1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['SECTION 1'], ['CED', 'D', 'C1']])
section_2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['SECTION 2'], ['BCD', 'FGH', 'CE', 'L1', 'L2']])
section_3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['SECTION 3'], ['A6', 'AB', 'KLMN', 'A5']])

columns = section_1.append(section_2).append(section_3)
df = pd.DataFrame([[None]*len(columns)], columns=columns)
```

```
print(df)

  SECTION 1             SECTION 2                         SECTION 3                  
        CED     D    C1       BCD   FGH    CE    L1    L2        A6    AB  KLMN    A5
0      None  None  None      None  None  None  None  None      None  None  None  None
```

I tried this code but it giving me an empty result :

```
wanted = df.stack(0, dropna=False).filter(regex=r'[^[A-Z]\d]').unstack()
print(wanted)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0]
```

I expect this output :

```
  SECTION 1          SECTION 2               SECTION 3                  
        CED     D          BCD   FGH    CE          AB  KLMN   
0      None  None         None  None  None        None  None
```

Do you guys have an idea on how to deal with this problem ? I'm very interested on how to fix my regex approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to drop columns matching the regex:

```py
df = df.drop(filter(lambda c:re.match(r'[A-Z]\d+$', c[1]), df.columns), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  SECTION 1       SECTION 2             SECTION 3
        CED     D       BCD   FGH    CE        AB  KLMN
0      None  None      None  None  None      None  None
```

Note that your addition of `[]` around the regex in your question changes its meaning completely. See the explanation at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mRA6bH/1).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a less concise but perhaps slightly more efficient way for a dataframe with many columns and repeating column values:

```
col_codes_to_drop = df.columns.levels[1].str.match(r'[A-Z]\d$')
cols_to_drop = col_codes_to_drop[df.columns.codes[1]]
df = df.loc[:, ~cols_to_drop]
```

Output:

```
  SECTION 1       SECTION 2             SECTION 3      
        CED     D       BCD   FGH    CE        AB  KLMN
0      None  None      None  None  None      None  None
```

The reason I think it might be faster is that it only does the regex once on each unique column value, and is fully vectorized (but I haven't tested it's actual efficiency).

Unless performance is an issue, I wouldn't recommend this since @Nick's answer is much easier to read.